# Android ActionMode Icons color white

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-styles

I tried to set action mode icons color to white (copy, paste, share etc...).
Im using AppCompat support. I know i can use this:

```
<style name="Widget.ActionMode">
    <item name="actionModeCutDrawable">@drawable/abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha</item>
    <item name="actionModeCopyDrawable">@drawable/abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha</item>
    <item name="actionModePasteDrawable">@drawable/abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha</item>
    <item name="actionModeSelectAllDrawable">@drawable/abc_ic_menu_selectall_mtrl_alpha</item>
    <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha</item>
</style>
```

But i dont want to set image drawables, just to set the color.
I think that android take the icons color by the theme but i cant change it by this way, so maybe not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was that in my light theme is used my style with:

```
 parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

So the icons tint to black color by default.

The Solution was to add this line to my light style:

```
<item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
```